# Table of contents based on custom heading style

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, table-of-contents

I'm pretty sure you can do this, one of the systems analysts at an old company I worked at had this set up. Basically I want a table of contents in my page, but I don't want it based on the standard "Heading 1", "Heading 2" styles.

I've added my own style "Question":
[image]

So now wherever I have a question I make it a question style. Now I want a summary of all my questions at the bottom of the document. I'm pretty sure I need some kind of "Table of Contents":
[image]

But I can't quite figure out how to associate my "table of contents", contents with my style "question"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

1. References tab
2. Table of contents -> Insert table of contents
3. Options button

[image]

4. Go though and remove the numbers against **all** items in style:

[image]

5. Add a number corresponding to the level you wish against the heading you wish, in my case a 1 against "Question"

[image]